# Embedding a Java (.jar) file within a Mac Application

Tags: java, objective-c, macos, jar, embed

I need to have a .jar file run within my main NSWindow, how can I do this?

I have been looking at Apple's example for ["JavaFrameEmbedding"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/JavaFrameEmbeddingDemo/), and seem to be able to run it without any Java exceptions (previously I had exceptions), however I cannot see the applet. They use the JavaFrameView which is part of the JavaFrameEmbedding framework, although I can't find *any* documentation about this at all. This is using Lion (I have also tried on Snow Leopard without success).

Comment: Is it an Applet? Then you should just create a WebView and load a HTML describing the applet.

Comment: It's a .jar, if anyone knows how to run that in HTML let me know. That was my first thought but I canned it after having some troubles with it.

Answer (score 1):

Download [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/JavaFrameEmbeddingDemo/Introduction/Intro.html) puppy and dig through it.

If you want to make the `NSWindow` in java and have the program run from there try something like this:

```
import com.apple.cocoa.application.*;
import com.apple.cocoa.foundation.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        NSApplication nsapp = NSApplication.sharedApplication();
        NSRect rect = new NSRect(500, 500, 500, 500);

        NSWindow.MiniaturizableWindowMask;;
        NSWindow window = new NSWindow(rect, style, NSWindow.Buffered,
false);
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window);
        nsapp.run();

    }

}
```

Comment: That's what I linked to in my original question, I just don't get why the JavaFrameView doesn't show anything. I don't have access to the source for the Java stuff, I've just got the .jar I need to build things around.

Comment: Link is broken :(