# How to access classes and its relevant method of JAR into MacOsX application (Objective-C)

Tags: java, objective-c, macos, jar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using a Java library in an Objective-C Mac app, and putting that app on the Mac App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623284/using-a-java-library-in-an-objective-c-mac-app-and-putting-that-app-on-the-mac)

I am developing for Mac-Osx application in Objective-C. I have one JAR file which contain some proprietary classes and its relevant methods. I want to use those methods into my Objective-C program/Code/Application.

How can i do that ?

Any help regarding this is admirable.

Thanks..!

In code below , i am getting **bad access** at Line  **(*env)->GetJavaVM(env, pvm);** and **JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs** is shown as deprecated(warning). **outCreatedVMCount** is always 0.

```
- (JNIEnv *)getJNIEnv
{
    static JNIEnv* sAppKitEnv = NULL;
    static JavaVM *sJVM = NULL;

    if (sAppKitEnv == NULL) {       
        if (sJVM == NULL) {
            JavaVM *createdJVMs;
            jint outCreatedVMCount;
            if (JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs(&createdJVMs, sizeof(createdJVMs), &outCreatedVMCount) == 0) {
                if (outCreatedVMCount > 0) {
                    sJVM = createdJVMs;
                }
            }
        }

        // If we didn't find one, we're stuck.
        if (sJVM != NULL) {
            (*sJVM)->AttachCurrentThreadAsDaemon(sJVM, (void **)&sAppKitEnv, nil);
        }
    }

    return sAppKitEnv;
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

    [self performSelector:@selector(initvm) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];

}

-(void) initvm
{
    JavaVM **pvm;
    //void **pJNIEnv;
    JavaVMInitArgs *args;
    JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs(&args);
    JNIEnv *env=[self getJNIEnv];
    (*env)->GetJavaVM(env, pvm);
}
```

Comment: Can you call it as an external process?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a Java library in an Objective-C Mac app, and putting that app on the Mac App Store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623284/using-a-java-library-in-an-objective-c-mac-app-and-putting-that-app-on-the-mac), [Embedding a jar file withing a Mac application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990103/embedding-a-java-jar-file-within-a-mac-application)

Comment: I want to use methods written in class those are bundled inside JAR.
I dont know weather to call it external process or not. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Is there any way to conver JAR file to Static Library of Objective-C or something like that?
Like "JAR->TO->DLL" in .Net framework ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a bridge between Cocoa and Java, but it's deprecated and not really well documented. Supposedly, it still works though. Read more [here](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/JavaBridge).

Good luck! Tell us all how it works out :)